# Use of promise after return from service Angular 5

Tags: angular, http, angular-promise

In Angular app, I have created a "config.json" in assets folder where I have stored some settings regarding App to use further.

json data in config.json is

```
{
    "config":{
    "worker_url":"http//:domainname/abc"   
    }
}
```

From my component I am calling a service Method to get the data from config.json.

```
 this.app_config = this._configService.getConfigResponse().then( (res) => {
    return res;
  });
 // app_config is Object;
   console.log(this.app_config);
```

I have a fuction in Service called "ConfigServices"

```
getConfigResponse() {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let apiURL = this._configFilePath;
    this.http.get(apiURL)
      .toPromise()
      .then(
        res => { // Success
         this.results = res.json().config;  
      //   console.log(res.json().config);
          resolve(this.results);
        },
        msg => { // Error
        reject(msg);
        }
      );
  });
  return promise;
}
```

The results in console log is:

[image]

Dont understand how to get this json in array to use it futher.

Comment: Some users on stackoverflow just intead of commenting on the question if didnt understand or currecting it, just down votes the question

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your problem is those lines:

```
this.app_config = this._configService.getConfigResponse().then( (res) => {
    return res;
 });
```

try to rewrite it as

```
this._configService.getConfigResponse().then( (res) => {
    this.app_config = res;
});
```

If you can use async/await, you can rewrite your code as:

```
this.app_config = await this._configService.getConfigResponse();
```